# R Apollo: how to add attribute in Hybrid_LC_with_OL model

Tags: r

I try to add membership attribute in `Hybrid_LC_with_OL` model example.

I just add two parameters and one variable to in membership.

```
b_second_pref_a = 0,b_second_pref_b = 0,
```

and

```
##### Changed #######
  V=list()
  V[["class_a"]] = delta_A + b_second_pref_a * second_pref
  V[["class_b"]] = delta_B + b_second_pref_b * second_pref
```

I guess there is something wrong in latent variable.

Here is the code

```
# ################################################################# #
#### LOAD LIBRARY AND DEFINE CORE SETTINGS                       ####
# ################################################################# #

### Initialise
rm(list = ls())
library(apollo)

apollo_initialise()

### Set core controls
apollo_control = list(
  modelName  = "Hybrid_LC_with_OL",
  modelDescr = "Hybrid latent class choice model on drug choice data, using ordered measurement model for indicators",
  indivID    = "ID",
  nCores     = 5,
  outputDirectory = "output"
)

# ################################################################# #
#### LOAD DATA AND APPLY ANY TRANSFORMATIONS                     ####
# ################################################################# #

### Loading data from package
### if data is to be loaded from a file (e.g. called data.csv), 
### the code would be: database = read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE)
database = apollo_drugChoiceData
### for data dictionary, use ?apollo_swissRouteChoiceData

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE MODEL PARAMETERS                                     ####
# ################################################################# #

### Vector of parameters, including any that are kept fixed in estimation
apollo_beta = c(# Choice parameters
  b_brand_Artemis_A     = 0, b_brand_Artemis_B     = 0,
  b_brand_Novum_A       = 0, b_brand_Novum_B       = 0.1,
  b_brand_BestValue_A   = 0, b_brand_BestValue_B   = 0.1,
  b_brand_Supermarket_A = 0, b_brand_Supermarket_B = 0.1,
  b_brand_PainAway_A    = 0, b_brand_PainAway_B    = 0.1,
  b_country_CH_A        = 0, b_country_CH_B        = 0,
  b_country_DK_A        = 0, b_country_DK_B        = 0,
  b_country_USA_A       = 0, b_country_USA_B       = 0,
  b_country_IND_A       = 0, b_country_IND_B       = 0,
  b_country_RUS_A       = 0, b_country_RUS_B       = 0,
  b_country_BRA_A       = 0, b_country_BRA_B       = 0,
  b_char_standard_A     = 0, b_char_standard_B     = 0,
  b_char_fast_A         = 0, b_char_fast_B         = 0,
  b_char_double_A       = 0, b_char_double_B       = 0,
  b_risk_A              = 0, b_risk_B              = 0,
  b_price_A             = 0, b_price_B             = 0,
  lambda_A              = 1, lambda_B              = 1, 
  # Class allocation parameters
  delta_A = 0, delta_B = 0, 
  b_second_pref_a = 0,b_second_pref_b = 0,
  # Measurement equations parameters
  zeta_quality      = 1, zeta_ingredient   = 1, zeta_patent       = 1, zeta_dominance    = 1, 
  tau_quality_1     =-2, tau_quality_2     =-1, tau_quality_3     = 1, tau_quality_4     = 2, 
  tau_ingredients_1 =-2, tau_ingredients_2 =-1, tau_ingredients_3 = 1, tau_ingredients_4 = 2, 
  tau_patent_1      =-2, tau_patent_2      =-1, tau_patent_3      = 1, tau_patent_4      = 2, 
  tau_dominance_1   =-2, tau_dominance_2   =-1, tau_dominance_3   = 1, tau_dominance_4   = 2)

### Vector with names (in quotes) of parameters to be kept fixed at their starting value in apollo_beta, use apollo_beta_fixed = c() if none
apollo_fixed = c("b_brand_Artemis_A", "b_country_USA_A", "b_char_standard_A", "delta_A","b_second_pref_a",
                 "b_brand_Artemis_B", "b_country_USA_B", "b_char_standard_B")

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE RANDOM COMPONENTS                                    ####
# ################################################################# #

### Set parameters for generating draws
apollo_draws = list(
  interDrawsType = "halton", 
  interNDraws    = 100,
  interNormDraws = c("eta")
)

### Create random parameters
apollo_randCoeff=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs){
  randcoeff = list()
  randcoeff[["LV"]] = eta
  return(randcoeff)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE LATENT CLASS COMPONENTS                              ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_lcPars=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs){
  lcpars = list()
  
  lcpars[["b_brand_Artemis"    ]] = list(b_brand_Artemis_A    , b_brand_Artemis_B    )
  lcpars[["b_brand_Novum"      ]] = list(b_brand_Novum_A      , b_brand_Novum_B      )
  lcpars[["b_brand_BestValue"  ]] = list(b_brand_BestValue_A  , b_brand_BestValue_B  )
  lcpars[["b_brand_Supermarket"]] = list(b_brand_Supermarket_A, b_brand_Supermarket_B)
  lcpars[["b_brand_PainAway"   ]] = list(b_brand_PainAway_A   , b_brand_PainAway_B   )
  lcpars[["b_country_CH"       ]] = list(b_country_CH_A       , b_country_CH_B       )
  lcpars[["b_country_DK"       ]] = list(b_country_DK_A       , b_country_DK_B       )
  lcpars[["b_country_USA"      ]] = list(b_country_USA_A      , b_country_USA_B      )
  lcpars[["b_country_IND"      ]] = list(b_country_IND_A      , b_country_IND_B      )
  lcpars[["b_country_RUS"      ]] = list(b_country_RUS_A      , b_country_RUS_B      )
  lcpars[["b_country_BRA"      ]] = list(b_country_BRA_A      , b_country_BRA_B      )
  lcpars[["b_char_standard"    ]] = list(b_char_standard_A    , b_char_standard_B    )
  lcpars[["b_char_fast"        ]] = list(b_char_fast_A        , b_char_fast_B        )
  lcpars[["b_char_double"      ]] = list(b_char_double_A      , b_char_double_B      )
  lcpars[["b_risk"             ]] = list(b_risk_A             , b_risk_B             )
  lcpars[["b_price"            ]] = list(b_price_A            , b_price_B            )
  lcpars[["lambda"             ]] = list(lambda_A             , lambda_B             )
  
##### Changed #######
  V=list()
  V[["class_a"]] = delta_A + b_second_pref_a * second_pref
  V[["class_b"]] = delta_B + b_second_pref_b * second_pref
  
  ### Settings for class allocation models
  classAlloc_settings = list(
    classes      = c(class_a=1, class_b=2), 
    utilities    = V  
  )
  
  lcpars[["pi_values"]] = apollo_classAlloc(classAlloc_settings)
  
  return(lcpars)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### GROUP AND VALIDATE INPUTS                                   ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()

# ################################################################# #
#### DEFINE MODEL AND LIKELIHOOD FUNCTION                        ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_probabilities=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs, functionality="estimate"){
  
  ### Initialise
  apollo_attach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs)
  on.exit(apollo_detach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs))
  P = list()
  
  ### Likelihood of indicators
  ol_settings1 = list(outcomeOrdered = attitude_quality, 
                      V              = zeta_quality*LV, 
                      tau            = list(tau_quality_1, tau_quality_2, tau_quality_3, tau_quality_4),
                      rows           = (task==1))
  ol_settings2 = list(outcomeOrdered = attitude_ingredients, 
                      V              = zeta_ingredient*LV, 
                      tau            = list(tau_ingredients_1, tau_ingredients_2, tau_ingredients_3, tau_ingredients_4), 
                      rows           = (task==1))
  ol_settings3 = list(outcomeOrdered = attitude_patent, 
                      V              = zeta_patent*LV, 
                      tau            = list(tau_patent_1, tau_patent_2, tau_patent_3, tau_patent_4), 
                      rows           = (task==1))
  ol_settings4 = list(outcomeOrdered = attitude_dominance, 
                      V              = zeta_dominance*LV, 
                      tau            = list(tau_dominance_1, tau_dominance_2, tau_dominance_3, tau_dominance_4), 
                      rows           = (task==1))
  P[["indic_quality"]]     = apollo_ol(ol_settings1, functionality)
  P[["indic_ingredients"]] = apollo_ol(ol_settings2, functionality)
  P[["indic_patent"]]      = apollo_ol(ol_settings3, functionality)
  P[["indic_dominance"]]   = apollo_ol(ol_settings4, functionality)
  P[["indic_quality"]]     = apollo_panelProd(P[["indic_quality"]]    , apollo_inputs, functionality)
  P[["indic_ingredients"]] = apollo_panelProd(P[["indic_ingredients"]], apollo_inputs, functionality)
  P[["indic_patent"]]      = apollo_panelProd(P[["indic_patent"]]     , apollo_inputs, functionality)
  P[["indic_dominance"]]   = apollo_panelProd(P[["indic_dominance"]]  , apollo_inputs, functionality)
  
  ### Likelihood of choices inside each class
  S <- 2
  for(s in 1:S){
    ### Utilities for alternatives
    V = list()
    V[["alt1"]] = b_brand_Artemis[[s]]  *(brand_1=="Artemis")   + b_brand_Novum[[s]]      *(brand_1=="Novum")                                                     + b_country_CH[[s]]* (country_1=="Switzerland") + b_country_DK[[s]] *(country_1=="Denmark") + b_country_USA[[s]]*(country_1=="USA")                                               + b_char_standard[[s]]*(char_1=="standard") + b_char_fast[[s]]*(char_1=="fast acting") + b_char_double[[s]]*(char_1=="double strength") + b_risk[[s]]*side_effects_1 + b_price[[s]]*price_1 + lambda[[s]]*LV
    V[["alt2"]] = b_brand_Artemis[[s]]  *(brand_2=="Artemis")   + b_brand_Novum[[s]]      *(brand_2=="Novum")                                                     + b_country_CH[[s]]* (country_2=="Switzerland") + b_country_DK[[s]] *(country_2=="Denmark") + b_country_USA[[s]]*(country_2=="USA")                                               + b_char_standard[[s]]*(char_2=="standard") + b_char_fast[[s]]*(char_2=="fast acting") + b_char_double[[s]]*(char_2=="double strength") + b_risk[[s]]*side_effects_2 + b_price[[s]]*price_2 + lambda[[s]]*LV
    V[["alt3"]] = b_brand_BestValue[[s]]*(brand_3=="BestValue") + b_brand_Supermarket[[s]]*(brand_3=="Supermarket") + b_brand_PainAway[[s]]*(brand_3=="PainAway") + b_country_USA[[s]]*(country_3=="USA")         + b_country_IND[[s]]*(country_3=="India")   + b_country_RUS[[s]]*(country_3=="Russia") + b_country_BRA[[s]]*(country_3=="Brazil") + b_char_standard[[s]]*(char_3=="standard") + b_char_fast[[s]]*(char_3=="fast acting")                                                  + b_risk[[s]]*side_effects_3 + b_price[[s]]*price_3
    V[["alt4"]] = b_brand_BestValue[[s]]*(brand_4=="BestValue") + b_brand_Supermarket[[s]]*(brand_4=="Supermarket") + b_brand_PainAway[[s]]*(brand_4=="PainAway") + b_country_USA[[s]]*(country_4=="USA")         + b_country_IND[[s]]*(country_4=="India")   + b_country_RUS[[s]]*(country_4=="Russia") + b_country_BRA[[s]]*(country_4=="Brazil") + b_char_standard[[s]]*(char_4=="standard") + b_char_fast[[s]]*(char_4=="fast acting")                                                  + b_risk[[s]]*side_effects_4 + b_price[[s]]*price_4
    ### Define settings for MNL model component
    mnl_settings = list(
      alternatives = c(alt1=1, alt2=2, alt3=3, alt4=4),
      choiceVar    = best,
      utilities    = V
    )
    ### Compute within-class choice probabilities using MNL model
    P[[paste0("Class_",s)]] = apollo_mnl(mnl_settings, functionality)
    
    ### Take product across observation for same individual
    P[[paste0("Class_",s)]] = apollo_panelProd(P[[paste0("Class_",s)]], apollo_inputs ,functionality)
  }
  
  ### Compute latent class model probabilities
  lc_settings  = list(inClassProb = P[paste0("Class_", 1:S)], classProb=pi_values)
  P[["choice"]] = apollo_lc(lc_settings, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  
  ### Comment out as necessary
  P = apollo_combineModels(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  P = apollo_avgInterDraws(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  P = apollo_prepareProb(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  return(P)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### CALCULATE LL AT STARTING VALUES                             ####
# ################################################################# #

apollo_llCalc(apollo_beta, apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)

#-- edit to add note to console---
#Calculating LL of each model component...Not applicable to all #components.
#[1] NA


# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL ESTIMATION                                            ####
# ################################################################# #

model = apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, 
                         apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)
```

Editors note: That's where the error was thrown and the processing stopped. It was preceded by a long bit of output:

```
#-------beginning of console output-----
Preparing user-defined functions.
WARNING: The pre-processing of 'apollo_probabilities' failed in initial testing. Your model may
  still run, but this indicates a potential problem. Please contact the developers for
  assistance! 

  Current process will resume in 5 seconds unless interrupted by the user.....
```

Inserint break in code block to highlight the advice to contact package authors.

```
#-- console output continues ...........
Testing likelihood function...
Apollo found a model component of type classAlloc without a componentName. The name was
  set to "classAlloc" by default.
INFORMATION: Setting "avail" is missing, so full availability is assumed. 
Apollo found a model component of type OL without a componentName. The name was set to
  "indic_quality" by default.
INFORMATION: No coding provided for Ordered model component "indic_quality", so assuming
  outcomeOrdered goes from 1 to 5 

Overview of choices for model component indic_quality:
                            1     2     3   4     5
Times chosen              220 151.0 398.0 130 101.0
Percentage chosen overall  22  15.1  39.8  13  10.1
Apollo found a model component of type OL without a componentName. The name was set to
  "indic_ingredients" by default.
INFORMATION: No coding provided for Ordered model component "indic_ingredients", so assuming
  outcomeOrdered goes from 1 to 5 

Overview of choices for model component indic_ingredients:
                              1     2     3     4     5
Times chosen              113.0 136.0 372.0 164.0 215.0
Percentage chosen overall  11.3  13.6  37.2  16.4  21.5
Apollo found a model component of type OL without a componentName. The name was set to
  "indic_patent" by default.
INFORMATION: No coding provided for Ordered model component "indic_patent", so assuming outcomeOrdered
  goes from 1 to 5 

Overview of choices for model component indic_patent:
                              1     2     3     4     5
Times chosen              211.0 171.0 358.0 121.0 139.0
Percentage chosen overall  21.1  17.1  35.8  12.1  13.9
Apollo found a model component of type OL without a componentName. The name was set to
  "indic_dominance" by default.
INFORMATION: No coding provided for Ordered model component "indic_dominance", so assuming
  outcomeOrdered goes from 1 to 5 

Overview of choices for model component indic_dominance:
                             1     2     3   4     5
Times chosen              96.0 132.0 443.0 170 159.0
Percentage chosen overall  9.6  13.2  44.3  17  15.9
Apollo found a model component of type MNL without a componentName. The name was set to
  "Class_1" by default.
Setting "avail" is missing, so full availability is assumed.

Overview of choices for MNL model component Class_1:
                                     alt1     alt2     alt3     alt4
Times available                  10000.00 10000.00 10000.00 10000.00
Times chosen                      3403.00  3546.00  1517.00  1534.00
Percentage chosen overall           34.03    35.46    15.17    15.34
Percentage chosen when available    34.03    35.46    15.17    15.34

Apollo found a model component of type MNL without a componentName. The name was set to
  "Class_2" by default.
Setting "avail" is missing, so full availability is assumed.

Overview of choices for MNL model component Class_2:
                                     alt1     alt2     alt3     alt4
Times available                  10000.00 10000.00 10000.00 10000.00
Times chosen                      3403.00  3546.00  1517.00  1534.00
Percentage chosen overall           34.03    35.46    15.17    15.34
Percentage chosen when available    34.03    35.46    15.17    15.34

Apollo found a model component of type LC without a componentName. The name was set to
  "choice" by default.

Summary of class allocation for model component choice:
         Mean prob.
Class_1      0.5000
Class_2      0.5000
The class allocation probabilities for model component "choice" are calculated at the
  observation level in 'apollo_lcPars', but are used in 'apollo_probabilities' to
  multiply within class probabilities that are at the individual level. Apollo will
  average the class allocation probabilities across observations for the same individual
  level before using them to multiply the within-class probabilities. If your class
  allocation probabilities are constant across choice situations for the same individual,
  then this is of no concern. If your class allocation probabilities however vary across
  choice tasks, then you should change your model specification in 'apollo_probabilities'
  to only call 'apollo_panelProd' after calling 'apollo_lc'.
Error in pi * p : non-conformable arrays
#------end of console output------------

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL OUTPUTS                                               ####
# ################################################################# #

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO SCREEN)                               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_modelOutput(model)
```

Here is the error：

> Error in pi * p : non-conformable arrays